# Typescript Interface - make type of one property dependent of type of another property

Tags: typescript

I have some Interfaces which look like this:

```
export enum SortValueType {
  String = 'string',
  Number = 'number',
  Date = 'date',
}


export interface SortConfig {
  key: string;
  direction: SortDirection;
  type: SortValueType;
  options?: {
    sortBy?: 'year' | 'day';
  };
}
```

I would like to make it possible  to extend this so that the possible types of `options.sortBy` should be dependent on the `type`. I am creating iteratees depending on `type` so it should not be possible to create an Object where `type` is `string` and `options.sortBy` has a value of `year`.

This is the `getIteratee` function:

```
 private getIteratee(config: SortConfig) {
    if (config.type === SortValueType.String) {
      return item => _lowerCase(item[config.key]);
    }

    if (config.type === SortValueType.Date) {
      const sortBy = _get(config, 'options.sortBy') as 'year' | 'day';

      if (!!sortBy && sortBy === 'year') {
        return item =>
          !!item[config.key]
            ? new Date(item[config.key]).getFullYear()
            : undefined;
      }

      if (!!sortBy && sortBy === 'day') {
        return item =>
          !!item[config.key]
            ? new Date(item[config.key].toJSON().split('T')[0])
            : undefined;
      }
    }

    return config.key;
  }
```

I am also open to more generic solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```js
export enum SortValueType {
  String = 'string',
  Number = 'number',
  Date = 'date',
}

type SortDirection = string;

export interface SortConfig<T extends SortValueType> {
  key: string;
  direction: SortDirection;
  type: T;
  options:
    T extends SortValueType.Date
      ? { sortBy: 'year' | 'day'; }
      : { sortBy?: undefined };
}
// OK:
let dateConfig: SortConfig<SortValueType.Date> = {
  key: "key",
  direction: "left",
  type: SortValueType.Date,
  options: { sortBy: 'year' }
}

// Not OK:
let numberConfig: SortConfig<SortValueType.Number> = {
  key: "key",
  direction: "left",
  type: SortValueType.Number,
  options: { sortBy: 'year' }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=2#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)

The `sortBy?: undefined` is required, because TypeScript doesn't block extra properties by default. If you just use `{}` then `{ sortBy: 'year' }` is actually valid, as it is assignable to `{}`.

You can tweak the exact type of `options` from there, depending on how exactly you want each type's options to work.

To make getIteratee work nicely, you'll want to change the parameter to `SortConfig<any>`, define a type guard, and use that to narrow down the type for each case. Like so:

```js
function isConfigType<T extends SortValueType>(
    config: SortConfig<any>, type: T
): config is SortConfig<T> {
  return config.type === type;
}

function getIteratee(config: SortConfig<any>) {
    if (isConfigType(config, SortValueType.String)) {
        // The type of 'config' here is SortConfig<SortValueType.String>;
    } ...
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly type I am looking for. Is it possible to switch in `getIteratee` depending on this type?

Comment: Answering the last comment by myself: In this case I would need to write a type guard.

Comment: I've added a quick example - seems that TypeScript won't infer it for you just by checking `config.type`, but you can easily use a type guard function to do it.