# TypeScript interface property dependent on previous property - concise solution for many possible cases

Tags: typescript

## Background

There are various ways of implementing this. Some ways are linked here:

[TypeScript: an interface property dependent on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426983/typescript-an-interface-property-dependent-on-another)

[How to make Typescript interface property to be depended on another property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68535256/how-to-make-typescript-interface-property-to-be-depended-on-another-property)

[Typescript Interface - make type of one property dependent of type of another property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174027/typescript-interface-make-type-of-one-property-dependent-of-type-of-another-pr)

---

## Approach

I've tried these approaches and similar approaches, and found that in my situation, the accepted answer in the third link shared above is most fitting.

I have a specific question on this that I thought would be more appropriate as its own question.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    One = 'One',
    Two = 'Two',
    Three = 'Three',
    // And possibly many more to come.
}

interface MyInterface<T extends MyEnum>
{
    prop1: string,
    prop2: boolean,
    prop3: T,
    prop4: T extends MyEnum.One
           ? OneSpecificInterface
           : T extends MyEnum.Two
           ? TwoSpecificInterface
           : T extends MyEnum.Three
           ? ThreeSpecificInterface
           : // And so on.
}
```

`prop3` can be any value of `MyEnum`, and `prop4` is conditional on the value of `prop3`.

For example, if `prop3` is `MyEnum.One`, then the value passed to `prop4` should be `OneSpecificInterface` (an interface with values specific to that data type).

The values passed to `prop4` would likely be very different from each other, so it's not workable to create one interface to encompass all of them. But at the same time, there does need to be one interface to encompass these four props, which is what led me to this solution.

---

## Question

The solution works fine, but you can see how as `MyEnum` grows, the ternaries in `prop4` will get longer and longer.

Is there a more elegant or concise way of doing that check in `prop4`?

---

If there isn't a more elegant or concise way of doing this using the basic approach above, that wouldn't be the end of the world, since this is straight-forward enough - but I'd like to know, and haven't been able to confirm it on my own yet.

I'm open to other kinds of type-checking that accomplish the same thing, but based on the several I already tried, I found this to be the best and most readable/straight-forward approach.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without pseudocode/private types like `OneSpecificInterface` so we can easily give you a testable suggestion that works the same for everyone.

Comment: @jcalz Unfortunately, I don't have the details for all the interfaces yet, since I'm early in the design phase. The only interface finalized at this point has a number of properties all of which have typing of `number | string`. The others haven't been created yet, so I don't know their shape, how many props they'll have, or their props' typing. What I do know is that 1) there'll be more, and 2) they'll have different props and typing. That's what led me to ask this question - so I can start with an accommodating design for the wrapper interface that can handle these different data types.

Comment: ① A [mre] doesn't mean "implement everything before you know it", it means "give us something we can all play with".  You have to define those interfaces or it will be an error.  We can make guesses about them and hope they don't affect the answer, but that should be part of the question, not individual answers. ② Assuming my guess doesn't affect anything, I'd suggest writing a single indexed access instead of a series of conditional types, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbrGdm) shows. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Understood, thanks for the clarification! Your playground link is exactly what I was looking for, and much more concise than the ternary I originally used. Please post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, might be a little while before I get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to represent a mapping from the members of an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) to corresponding interface types.  TypeScript enums can either have number or string values, and are therefore *keylike*.  And so the language naturally supports a mapping between keylike types and arbitrary types: it's just an [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types).  For example:

```
interface Prop4 {
    [MyEnum.One]: OneSpecificInterface,
    [MyEnum.Two]: TwoSpecificInterface,
    [MyEnum.Three]: ThreeSpecificInterface
    // etc
}
```

And then instead of writing a long series of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to find the value corresponding to a given enum member, you can use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to look it up directly:

```
interface MyInterface<T extends MyEnum> {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: boolean,
    prop3: T,
    prop4: Prop4[T]
}
```

This should scale and perform fairly well.  Note that this is a bit of an off-label use of an interface, since there's not obviously a value of type `Prop4` lying around... but often times it turns out that values of that type or of a related type do tend to pop up naturally:

```
declare const prop4: Prop4; 

function mockMyInterface<T extends MyEnum>(t: T): MyInterface<T> {
    return {
        prop1: "abc",
        prop2: true,
        prop3: t,
        prop4: prop4[t]
    }
}
```

Here you have a function that produces a mock `MyInterface<T>` given a value `t` of type `T`, and it does so by looking up `t` in an object of type `Prop4`.  This may or may not be the way your particular use cases will go, but it's indicative of how this sort of representation can be leveraged beyond pure type-level lookups.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Super helpful linking to official docs for various concepts.